# How to map two json.txt files on android?

Tags: android, json

I have two json.txt files on my android project under assest folder.
Here i need to map that two json files for consume some values from both .txt files.
Can any one give some sample source for this situation.

Suggestion please

Thanks for your precious time!...

Answer (score 0):

First you need to read a file in assets to a string. Do something like:

```
InputStream in = getAssets().open("jsonfile.txt");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
int oneByte;
while ((oneByte = in.read()) != -1) {
    baos.write(oneByte);
}
String json = baos.toString();
```

Once you have the JSON file as a String pass it to a [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and use the different get() methods to retrieve the data you want.